# Java servlet - log4j messages getting mixed

Tags: java, servlets, log4j, log4j2

I log all the request params coming to my servlet. What is happening is that the request params are getting mixed. Since servlet handles each request in new thread so I understand that my messages will get mixed up. 
But how can I ensure that all the params of a request will get printed only then the params from next request will get printed.

log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">../</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="LogFile"
        fileName="${log-path}/standalone/log/myApp/app.log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/standalone/log/myApp/%d{yyyy}/%d{MM}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz">

        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>

        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
        </Policies>

    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Code:

```
logger.info("-----Request Details Begins-----");
        logger.info("Client IP Address------> " + ipAddress);
        logger.info("Requested Service------> " + url);

        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
            for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                String paramValue = paramValues[i];
                if (dontLog(paramName)) {
                    paramValue = "XXXXXX";
                } else if ("requestParams".equalsIgnoreCase(paramName)) {
                    //TODO dont log sensitive data
                }
                logger.info("Request " + paramName + " ------> " + paramValue);
            }
        }
        logger.info("-----Request Details Ends-----");
```

Note: I don't want to print messages in single line.

Comment: use StringBuilder to create the total message, then print it in one go.

Comment: I have one more issue with this approach. I make some request over socket to some other system. I want to log the request/response. In this case also I am facing the same issue. The request and response are not printing together. Some other response is getting printed first. I know the reason is the response is coming late in this case hence it is getting printed late. But I want to print them together.

Comment: Is there something like synchronized for log4j?

Comment: Tried StringBuilder, it helped me to some extent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Log messages getting mixed up by different threads is expected behaviour. If you do not want to log a single line, just log one block of text - line breaks included. You always have to log your "event" with one log statement. If a logger would be synchronized, your application's performance would decrease dramatically. Your servlet's capability of serving multiple threads is a good thing - and nothing to be messed around with. If you used non-blocking technologies, your webserver would be capable of serving tens of thousands of requests in parallel. Take a guess what would happen if you synchronized your log statements.
Long story short: add the line breaks yourself. ;)